# How do I get a result from a recursive function without using a global variable?

Tags: c, recursion, global-variables

I wrote a function that reverses an integer (123 becomes 321) with recursion, and I was told that using global variables is bad practice, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the result from the function without using one. I tried declaring the variable inside the function, but then I get undesired results.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int result = 0;

int reverse_num(int num)
{
    int remainder = num % 10;
    
    if (num == 0) return 0;
    
    result *= 10;
    result += remainder;
    
    reverse_num(num / 10);
    
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    int num, reversed_num;
    
    printf("Insert number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    
    reversed_num = reverse_num(num);
    
    printf("Inverted number: %d", reversed_num);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way to do this is to have *another argument* just for the accumulated result. It can be accomplished in C by splitting your function into the one called by the user and the one that does all the work.

```
int reverse_num_helper(int num, int result)
{
    int remainder = num % 10;
    
    if (num == 0) return result;
    
    result *= 10;
    result += remainder;
    
    return reverse_num_helper(num / 10, result);
}

int reverse_num(int num)
{
    return reverse_num_helper(num, 0);
}
```

(In C++ you could combine the two into `int reverse_num(int num, int result = 0)`.)

**Notice how your function is essentially unchanged.**
We made only two minor modifications:

- returning `result` instead of zero when `num` *reaches* zero
- invoking recursion with the modified `result` value

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways.  One way involves finding the most significant decimal digit per each recursion.

Below is an inefficient example.

Works OK for some values 0 to near `INT_MAX/10`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int reverse_num(int num) {
  if (num < 10) {
    return num;
  }
  int pow10 = 10;
  while (num/pow10 >= 10) {
    pow10 *= 10;
  }
  int lead_digit = num/pow10;
  return reverse_num(num % pow10) * 10 + lead_digit;
}

int main() {
  printf("%d\n", reverse_num(123456789));
  printf("%d\n", reverse_num(1));
  printf("%d\n", reverse_num(100));
}
```

Output

```
987654321
1
1
```

Fails for others `printf("%d\n", reverse_num(123000789));` --> 987321.

---

Improved: recursive and efficient.

```
static int reverse_num_helper(int num, int power10) {
  if (power10 < 10) {
    return num;
  }
  return reverse_num_helper(num % power10, power10 / 10) * 10 + num / power10;
}

int reverse_num(int num) {
  int pow10 = 1;
  while (num / pow10 >= 10) {
    pow10 *= 10;
  }
  return reverse_num_helper(num, pow10);
}

int main() {
  printf("%d\n", reverse_num(123000789));
  printf("%d\n", reverse_num(123456789));
  printf("%d\n", reverse_num(123));
  printf("%d\n", reverse_num(1));
  printf("%d\n", reverse_num(100));
}
```

Output

```
987000321
987654321
321
1
1
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep it similar to your original code, only without the global variable, try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define RESET (-1)

int reverse_num(int num)
{
    static int result = 0;
    int remainder = num % 10;

    if (num < 0) {
        result = 0;
        return 0;
    }
    if (num == 0) return 0;
    result *= 10;
    result += remainder;
    reverse_num(num / 10);
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    int num, reversed_num;

    printf("Insert number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    reverse_num(RESET);
    reversed_num = reverse_num(num);
    printf("Inverted number: %d\n", reversed_num);
    return 0;
}
```

Here, I just make `result` into a local `static` variable in the function, which means it keeps its value even when the function returns (like a global variable, except that its scope is only within the function). The catch is that if you want to call it more than once, you need a way to reset the `result` value; I did this by using a negative value for `num` as a semaphore to reset.

Comment: What does the `reverse_num(RESET)` call do?

Comment: Presumably `RESET` is #defined to be zero. This is a bad solution. It just moves the global to a static local, requiring special magic goofiness to reset the result to zero. (Sorry)

Comment: Sorry I omitted the `#define` for `RESET`, which is `-1`. A negative value tells `reverse_num` to reset `result` to zero.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat more long-winded version of that given by @chux might be a bit clearer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count_places(int num);
int reverse_by_places(int num, int num_places);
int ipow(int base, int power);

int reverse_num(int num)
{
    return reverse_by_places(num, count_places(num)) / 10;
}

int ipow(int base, int power)
{
    if (power == 0)
        return 1;
    return base * ipow(base, power-1);
}

int count_places(int num)
{
    int i;
    if (num == 0)
        return 1;

    for (i = 0; num > 0; i++) 
    {
        num /= 10;
    }
    return i;
}


int reverse_by_places(int num, int num_places)
{
    int dividend = num / 10, remainder = num % 10;
    
    if (dividend == 0)
        return remainder * ipow(10, num_places);
    else
        return ((remainder * ipow(10, num_places)) + reverse_by_places(dividend, num_places-1));    
}

int main(void)
{
    int num, reversed_num;
    
    printf("Insert number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    
    reversed_num = reverse_num(num);
    
    printf("Inverted number: %d\n", reversed_num);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int Reverse(int n,int Len) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    return std::pow(10, Len-1)*(n % 10) + Reverse(n / 10, Len-1);
}



  //inside main
    Reverse(54321,5);

//Output Should be 12345
```

Comment: As this is an integer-only task, bringing `float`s in (using `pow`) is undesirable. Also, `std::pow` is a C++ syntax, and this is a C question.